# Work with individual Polygons of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, spatialdataframe

I'm trying to work with individual polygons of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (SPDF). I've seen these two questions: Using [`sapply` on SPDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35251/iterate-features-on-spatialpolygonsdataframe-in-r) and a [for-loop on a SPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254367/iterate-spatialpoints-and-spatialpolygonsdataframe-merge-in-r). The latter I thought may be helpful, but I don't understand the `%>%`-syntax and don't know how to apply it to conditional code.

I want to iterate over an SPDF, shrink (`gBuffer`) polygons, as long as they don't get smaller than 1 ha (10'000 m²), then maybe apply other steps to those polygons. Something like this:

```
# get shp file with multiple polygons, creates SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
shpA = shapefile(file.path(PATH_DATA, 'sample_test_A.shp'))

# iterate over shp and work with individual polygons
for (i in 1:length(shpA)) {
  # THIS DOESN'T GIVE ME A SPATIAL POLYGON I CAN WORK WITH:
  pol_temp = shpA[[1]] # or shpA@polygons[[i]]
  
  # create buffered polygon and check if it is > 1ha
  pol_buffered = gBuffer(shpA, width=-30)
  if(area(pol_buffered) > 10000){
    # replace polygon
    shpA[[1]] == pol_buffered
  }
  
  # maybe do some other stuff, like sampling the polygon
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you subset polygons using a bracket index is not with a double bracket try `shpA[1,]`. You also do not need to do this in a for loop.

Even though it is not polygon data, we can use the meuse data to illustrate

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
```

Create a variable buffer for the meuse points

```
b <- gBuffer(meuse, byid = TRUE, width = sample(10:500, nrow(meuse)))
```

Calculate areas for each polygon buffer

```
( a <- gArea(b, byid=TRUE) )
```

Now, to subset we can use `which` to create an index representing our query. If passed to a bracket index this can be used to subset the data. The `if` statement is helpful in avoiding the creation of an empty dataset due to a zero length the index resulting from no features meeting the query criteria.

```
( idx <- which( a > 100000) )
  if(length(idx) > 0)
    b.sub <- b[idx,]
```

If you know that your query criteria will return results, this could be distilled to one line of code (note; do not run if you already ran the above example).

```
b.sub <- b[which( gArea(b, byid=TRUE) > 100000),]
```

Check results

```
dim(b)
summary(gArea(b, byid=TRUE))

dim(b.sub)
summary(gArea(b.sub, byid=TRUE))
```

Now, across your two datasets, replacing polygons in shpA that meet the criteria of pol_buffered.

```
pol_buffered = gBuffer(shpA, byid=TRUE, width=-30)
  idx <- which(gArea(pol_buffered, byid=TRUE) > 10000)
shpA[idx,] <- pol_buffered[idx,]
```